Do we need standard guidelines for MathJax editing, in order to reduce superfluous editing?
I notice quite often that:

Edit proposals that are meant to improve MathJax typesetting, appear borderline with regards to being superfluous/helpful to the post
Some edit reviewers do a fair amount of tweaking as part of approving MathJax edits. Such tweaks themselves sometimes appear to be superfluous, although that is understandable insofar as, if someone needs to do some real improvements on an edit, it's not a big deal that he also changes the MathJax style a bit to one he thinks is slightly better.
Since I am also reviewing edit proposals, I also noticed that I myself have my own peculiar preferences, and that I will tweak the MathJax typesetting style slightly whenever I see something that goes too much against it, especially if I also think it really does improve readability. Again, even here I often wonder whether what I am doing is counted as superfluous or not, because what I find personally as more readable/clear, due to habit or any other reason, is by no means universal.

To give a few of examples, of things that I see come up in edit suggestions:

Some users change differentials from the normal styled $d$ to "$\mathrm{d}$", e.g. ($\mathrm{d}x, \mathrm{d}y$, etc. rather than $dx, dy$, etc.) - this is a choice I also go by.
Some users will space variables when they are multiplied together, e.g. write $F = \frac{1}{2}\ \rho\  v^2\  C_D A$ rather than $F = \frac{1}{2}\rho v^2 C_D A$. I personally prefer the latter option (though I have no strong opinion on this matter).
When it comes to something like vectors, there are many different conventions that users can and do choose from when editing. This is more often relevant when MathJaxifying a non-MathJax post (otherwise most people leave the vector style alone, which is a good policy I believe). I personally like to have three vectors as $\vec{v}$ while others prefer $\mathbf{v}$, but I prefer to save the latter bold face style for four vectors exclusively.

Anyway, my personal preferences are definitely irrelevant. I'm just wondering whether we could save some editorial reviewing efforts if we had such a guideline to adhere to, so when anyone edits a post they can do it the agreed way the first time, hopefully leading to quicker reviews and approvals.
The main question is whether we need MathJax guidelines for editing posts and for reviewing edit suggestions on posts. I am not suggesting that there should be any overarching MathJax guidelines that everyone should go by.
If a post is already MathJaxified, as long as it is understandable and well formatted, I think it's best to leave it alone.
Such editing guidelines can help us when we do have to either:

MathJaxify a post
Improve MathJax usage which is very poor


I think the much more important problem is that many (not only new!) users fail to use MathJax at all (and instead use screenshots or so)...

@TobiasFünke I agree, but that's something idk if we can do anything about. As long as people don't use it, or use it poorly, there will be MathJax related edits and edit suggestions, which is the background for this question...

The research-level mathematicians on MathOverflow don’t seem to enforce a standard on something as basic as differentials — most apparently just write $dx$ —  so I don’t see why we should care.

@Ghoster I wasn't trying to suggest any enforcement. Note that the title reads "Do we need standard guidelines for MathJax editing?", not guidelines for MathJax in general. The bottom line is, it could be nice to know which edits should be approved and which should be seen as superfluous more easily. For example if someone changes $mv^2/2$ to $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$, is it superfluous or helpful? If someone changes $F=m*a$ to $F=ma$, superfluous or helpful? etc.

While not explicitly stated in the Help Center documentation, I think it is safe to say that the fundamental guideline already exists and can be expressed as simply as this: are the proposed (non-superfluous & non-intent-altering) changes complete and make the post more readable/comprehendible?
If both parts are positive, then you should accept the edits. If both are negative, one should reject it (using the somewhat harsh No improvement whatsoever reason). If only one of the two, then either edit it yourself (using Improve edit or Reject & edit as you see fit) or, if you don't have the time to edit it, skip it or reject it with a custom reason (e.g., "Incomplete edit, needs X" or something similar).
So if someone wants to use $dx$, $d\,x$, $d\!x$, $\mathrm{d}x$, $\mathrm dx$, $\mathrm{d}\,x$, $\operatorname{d}\!x$, $\mathbb{d}x$ (all different commands), it probably shouldn't matter as all of us are going to understand the intent from the context surrounding it (okay, maybe that that blackboard font one might be a bit of a stretch, but there is someone out there who proposed it with unicode).


As to what is "superfluous", I have made arguments in the past that edits should be reserved for:

typographical errors
adding/modifying links
changing word choices

While I do state in that linked answer that typographical errors include LaTeX/MathJax fixes, my intent was not to say that $dx\,\to\,\mathrm{d}x$, for example, is fine in all cases. Instead, my intent is that someone should be able to fix posts where a user has written either no MathJax (i.e., F = mg sin theta), improper MathJax (e.g., writing $sin$ instead of $\sin$, not using \left(...\right), using $F=mg\sin\theta$ instead of $$F=mg\sin\theta$$) or broken MathJax (e.g., missing closing brace, using non-standard \ket).
Hence, if a user is only editing a post to change $dx$ to $\mathrm{d}x$ or just changing $\mathbf{v}$ to $\vec{v}$, these almost certainly should be rejected every time---this is also more important for old posts ($\geq$ 6M since last edit) as it pushes these older posts to the front page & removing newer content from being seen by users.
I would also argue that editing inline numbers (including units) to be MathJax (i.e., changing 9.81 m/s² to be $9.81\,\text{m/s}^2$) is actually harmful due to the font size/shape differences and required rendering for something that doesn't need it.
I was also reminded of this answer talking about \label and \eqref where the comments actually suggest to not use these due to potential conflicts of equation labelling in other answers (e.g., having two \label{eq:1} in the same URL links all \eqref{eq:1} to the first (rendered?) instance). Edits including these probably should be in the "reject" pile for that reason.

Thank you @KyleKanos. But I must say it's precisely my frequent indecision about what counts as "non-superfluous" that motivated this question. Often times, a thing isn't superfluous but it's so minor that it makes one wonder whether it justifies its place in the review queue. Of course, one possibility is just to decide that for any $\varepsilon>0$ of improvement, we approve the edit, but I'm not sure that it's a good idea to encourage these types of edit suggestions.

but it's so minor that it makes one wonder whether it justifies its place in the review queue that describes a superfluous edit which you should reject. Also, your comment raises a distinct question/point (what is a superfluous edit) to the main question you originally posed (guidance for MathJax). If you meant something different with your post, please either edit the question (while also allowing both posed answers to be valid) or ask a new one.

ok thanks, I edited my question to focus it on the subject of guidelines in the context of editing, e.g. deciding what will be superfluous, both with regards to edits I myself perform and with regards to reviewing edit suggestions.

@Amit updated with more details on edits

Thanks for the additions, these are very helpful!

I was also reminded of this answer talking about \label and \eqref where the comments actually suggest to not use these due to potential conflicts of equation labelling in other answers (e.g., having two \label{eq:1} in the same URL links all \eqref{eq:1} to the first (rendered?) instance). Edits including these probably should be in the "reject" pile for that reason.

this bit of info is actually so important, I think it justifies adding to your answer here too! Incidentally, I also noticed that usage of \label messes up the edit comparison ("side by side"), my hunch tells me it may be the same issue with the MathJax preview mentioned in this post you've linked to.

Done @Amit ${}{}{}$

My personal feeling is that writing a MathJax style guide — let alone enforcing such rules — is an impossibly bureaucratic task for a diverse community of volunteers which is as small as ours.  It's something that is done by paid professionals at journals, and that may or may not be done at larger community projects; see Wikipedia's style guide.  But Wikipedia has pages and pages of contentious bureaucratic policies.  I don't think we want that here.
One approach might be to choose a style guide from elsewhere as a recommendation.  I haven't read the Wikipedia guide above carefully, but it is aimed at non-mathematical or new-to-mathematics volunteers. The APS journal guidelines on mathematics are a brief bulleted list.  The NIST guidelines are likewise brief on mathematics in general, but they are delightfully fastidious about units.  The AMS style guide is quite extensive, but is very generous with occasions to "stet" ("preserve") the author's original notation.
(I use \vec v $\vec v$ because \mathbf v $\mathbf v$ has too many characters.  My major pet peeves are italicized symbols for element names and units. Helium-4 is $\rm ^4He,$ not $^4He$. An object's weight near Earth's surface is $mg=m\cdot 10\rm\ m/s^2$, which distinguishes the two meanings of the same letter.)

Thank you rob! I completely agree that it would be an overkill to have something like Wikipedia's guide, as you mention it's also meant to teach people how to typeset from scratch. I also thought more along the lines of a brief list for people who already are familiar with MathJax/LaTeX, that mainly sets the standard for some specific things that seem to come up again and again in edits; vectors and when to use italicized fonts being a couple of good examples indeed.
